# Why image in the ListView always shows the latest image?

Tags: android, image, listview, android-listview

In **Activity B**, there has `imageView` used to place the `selected image`. The `selected image` will then return to `listView` **A** if submit `button` is clicked. When the `listView` **A** is clicked, it should shows the image accordingly to the position and display on **Activity B** `imageView`.

**This is listView A**

[image]

When the first list is clicked, the image shown in `imageView` **B** is from the second list instead of first list. What's wrong here ?

**Activity B**

```
     Bitmap photo;

     private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

     if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) { //if  has value pass from A
      photo=getIntent().getParcelableExtra("photo");
      }

      private void activeGallery() {
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
      startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                                        Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            switch (requestCode) {
                case RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE:
                    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK & null != data) {
                        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                        String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null,
                                        null);
                        cursor.moveToFirst();
                        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                        cursor.close();
                        photo=decodeSampledBitmapFromUri(picturePath,200,200);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
                    }
                    break;
                  }


     submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) { // back to activity A 

                    Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                    returnIntent.putExtra("photo", photo);
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                    finish();

                }
            });
```

**Activity A**

```
Bitmap ReceiveImage;

listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // if   listView is clicked
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition = position;
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), B.class); // pass bitmap to B
                i.putExtra("photo", ReceiveImage);
                startActivityForResult(i, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });


      @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { // receive from Activity B and populate ListView A
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
                    ReceiveImage = data.getParcelableExtra("photo");
                    if (mClickedPosition == -1) {  // if icon clicked, add new list
                        if (obj != null)
                            obj.addNewItem(ReceiveImage);
                    }
                    else{
                        if (obj != null)
                            obj.changeItem(mClickedPosition,ReceiveImage);
                    }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: can you not store the image and pass the path with intent which would be better and what is `obj`

Comment: `obj` is the object of `MyCustomBaseAdapter`. The list can be updated and added, just that when the `listView` is clicked, it shows the latest image on `imageView` B

Comment: ok. You need to get the image when a row item is clicked at a certain index?. So how is `ReceiveImage` initialized and where?

Comment: I have declared on Activity A

Comment: yes but you said when user clicks a image at row index 0 you need that image passed to activity B right?? In that case you need to fetch items based on position

Comment: Thanks for your point. I did like this   `Object o = listview.getItemAtPosition(position);ImageAndText image =(ImageAndText) o; Bitmap photo=image.getImage();` and finally it display based on position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97665/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-tony).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I solve it by using this way

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() { // if listView is clicked
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                mClickedPosition = position;
                Object o = listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Bitmap photo=image.getImage();
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplication(), B.class);
                i.putExtra("photo", photo);
                startActivityForResult(i, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        });
```

`ImageAndText` is my **ArrayList**.